# Continuity of evaluation maps in the topology of compact convergence on $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that the evaluation maps $e_{x}:C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ given by $e_{x}(f):=f(x)$ are Lipschitz-continuous with respect to the metric $\left|f-\varphi\right|_{C}:=\sum_{k=1}^{k}\underset{0\leq x\leq k}{\max}2^{-k}\left|f(x)-\varphi(x)\right|_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}$.

I'm not too strong on topology, so rather than using abstract equivalences of the compact-convergence topology and the compact-open topology, where I know that the evaluation maps are continuous, I'd like to use the above metric (or a similar metric) for the compact-convergence topology.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your definition of the metric (check the sum index), but assuming you meant to define
$$ d_C(f,g) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \max_{x \in [0,k]} 2^{-k} \vert f(x) - g(x) \vert $$

then

$$ \vert e_x(f) - e_x(g) \vert = \vert f(x) - g(x) \vert \le 2^x \max_{y \in [0,x]} 
2^{-x} \vert f(y) - g(y) \vert \le 2^x d_C(f,g). $$